# How do I use a feature of a dependency only for testing?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

Say, I have a crate with a dependency that has an optional feature. Now this feature is mostly useful for testing, but the crate itself is a dependency for the whole code. Is it possible to instruct cargo to use the feature only for testing?

In my concrete example the optional feature depends on [quickcheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck), which I do not necessarily want to make a mandatory dependency for users of my crate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [use a feature](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[features]-section) for a [development dependency](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[dev-dependencies.*]-sections) just like you would for regular dependencies. In the case of `quickcheck`, its only feature is `collect_impls`, so you can add this to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dev-dependencies.quickcheck]
version = "*"
features = ["collect_impls"]
```

N.B. This was actually done wrong inside of `quickcheck`. I [just fixed it](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck/commit/fa1c6e969965debcd9e2dfbcc199a71e33cd73ea) in `0.1.29`.

Comment: So in my case quickcheck is itself a dev-dependency, but also a dependency of a feature of my dependency. In particular, I [implemented `Arbitrary` for the types in nalgebra](https://github.com/sebcrozet/nalgebra/pull/74). However, the compiler does not see the optional impls, when I try to depend on the feature as you suggested. I feel like I'm still missing something here.

Comment: Never mind, my problem was that I was mixing a github dep on quickcheck with nalgebra's crates.io dep on it. Too subtle…

Comment: In the case that the normal dependency isn't a semver-dependency (`version = "..."`), it works just to put the same path or the same Git repository URL.