# How can time be mocked in tests in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a method, which has a usage of UTC::now in its implementation...and for sure, this is making an attempt to write a test almost impossible.

The chronos library is being used for the time functionality

I am now basically looking for available mechanisms to mocking/stubbing time in tests in Rust.

Does anyone one have any recommendation on how to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't see why it's should be impossible, I see many way to handle it without special trick. For example, accept a range of time instead of exact.

Comment: how can accepting a range be a good idea?

Comment: for example, do a `UTC::now` then call your function then do another `UTC::now`, and check that the returned result is in this range. Without more precision on your use case I don't see the point to continue this thread. There is already question that ask how to mock a lib in rust

Answer (score 3):

By "chronos library" and "usage of UTC::now" I will assume [`chrono::Utc::now`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html#method.now) being the unambiguous method that is being referred to.  Claims that "this is making an attempt to write a test almost impossible" is simply untrue, because [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) (relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652318/what-does-cfgtest-do-when-placed-at-the-top-of-lib-rs)) may be used to replace the use declaration for a given item with a mocked or faked version that can be better controlled for when running under testing.

As a quick example, this is a function that would return whether or not the provided `DateTime` is in the future:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

pub fn in_the_future(dt: DateTime<chrono::Utc>) -> bool {
    dt > Utc::now()
}
```

In order to allow the injection of a mocked version of `Utc`, the `use` declaration should be modified to ensure that testing gets the mocked/stubbed version, that normal builds get the real thing, the conditional compilation should be used for `Utc`, so replace the original with the following:

```
#[cfg(test)]
use crate::mock_chrono::Utc;
#[cfg(not(test))]
use chrono::Utc;
// the other use will remain unchanged.
use chrono::DateTime;
```

The above configures the module to use the actual `chrono::Utc` when not built for testing, and the mocked version when built as part of testing.

Now to implement the mock itself - first, provide the `now()` method with the same signature that would return some value that can be controlled from the test.  The module `mock_chrono` will take the following form:

```
use chrono::{DateTime, NaiveDateTime};
use std::cell::Cell;

thread_local! {
    static TIMESTAMP: Cell<i64> = const { Cell::new(0) };
}

pub struct Utc;

impl Utc {
    pub fn now() -> DateTime<chrono::Utc> {
        DateTime::<chrono::Utc>::from_utc(
            TIMESTAMP.with(|timestamp| {
                NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp_opt(timestamp.get(), 0)
                    .expect("a valid timestamp set")
            }),
            chrono::Utc,
        )
    }
}

pub fn set_timestamp(timestamp: i64) {
    TIMESTAMP.with(|ts| ts.set(timestamp));
}
```

This module exports two symbols - the `Utc` that provide a custom `now()` method that can return a fully controlled `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`, plus the function `set_timestamp` that accepts an i64 offset from the unix epoch (this is done like so for simplicity of the data structure, it can be as complicated as the design requires).  Usage in a test may look something like this:

```
#[test]
fn test_record_past() {
    set_timestamp(1357908642);
    assert!(!in_the_future(
        "2012-12-12T12:12:12Z"
            .parse::<DateTime<Utc>>()
            .expect("valid timestamp"),
    ));
}

#[test]
fn test_record_future() {
    set_timestamp(1539706824);
    assert!(in_the_future(
        "2022-02-22T22:22:22Z"
            .parse::<DateTime<Utc>>()
            .expect("valid timestamp"),
    ));
}
```

Complete MVCE ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cbddef0fa2dd7164df0163f38a72a94b)):

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.26"
*/
use crate::demo::in_the_future;

pub fn main() {
    let dt = chrono::Utc::now();
    println!("{dt} is in the future: {}", in_the_future(dt));
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use crate::demo::in_the_future;
    use crate::mock_chrono::set_timestamp;
    use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

    #[test]
    fn test_record_past() {
        set_timestamp(1357908642);
        assert!(!in_the_future(
            "2012-12-12T12:12:12Z"
                .parse::<DateTime<Utc>>()
                .expect("valid timestamp"),
        ));
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_record_future() {
        set_timestamp(1539706824);
        assert!(in_the_future(
            "2022-02-22T22:22:22Z"
                .parse::<DateTime<Utc>>()
                .expect("valid timestamp"),
        ));
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod mock_chrono {
    use chrono::{DateTime, NaiveDateTime};
    use std::cell::Cell;

    thread_local! {
        static TIMESTAMP: Cell<i64> = const { Cell::new(0) };
    }

    pub struct Utc;

    impl Utc {
        pub fn now() -> DateTime<chrono::Utc> {
            DateTime::<chrono::Utc>::from_utc(
                TIMESTAMP.with(|timestamp| {
                    NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp_opt(timestamp.get(), 0)
                        .expect("a valid timestamp set")
                }),
                chrono::Utc,
            )
        }
    }

    pub fn set_timestamp(timestamp: i64) {
        TIMESTAMP.with(|ts| ts.set(timestamp));
    }
}

mod demo {
    #[cfg(test)]
    use crate::mock_chrono::Utc;
    use chrono::DateTime;
    #[cfg(not(test))]
    use chrono::Utc;

    pub fn in_the_future(dt: DateTime<chrono::Utc>) -> bool {
        dt > Utc::now()
    }
}
```

One might ask why the need for [`thread_local!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html), couldn't a more simple `static mut` be used for this simple test?  Well, while it is possible to [create a global mutable singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) and use it, that is very much the wrong approach, as [tests normally run concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639965/are-the-built-in-integration-tests-run-concurrently-or-sequentially) in their own threads. Rather than having every thread trying to wrestle control over a single variable (which either results in every test stamping over each other or creating a bottleneck), giving every thread their thread local own would be the logical sensible choice.

As it turns out, [`mock_instant`](https://docs.rs/mock_instant/latest/mock_instant/), a library that address a similar need, also use thread locals [in a similar manner](https://github.com/museun/mock_instant/blob/v0.3.0/src/lib.rs#L93-L96).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a very serious limitation to mocking in this way: `#[cfg(test)]` only works for the _current_ crate under test, and not any of its dependencies. This means that if you have any dependency, you now need to introduce _features_ for each of them, and when your crate is under test, enable the feature (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872009/how-do-i-use-a-feature-of-a-dependency-only-for-testing). It's a lot of boilerplate, and it's now possible to accidentally enable the feature outside of tests...

Comment: Well, I think I got what you meant about the side-effects and inner calls and dependencies, so to better demonstrate the example I got rid of all the other unrelated distracting cruft (that I lifted from one of my prototype projects), and just have a very simple function instead.

Comment: As for the limitation, it shouldn't be a big deal given that downstream packages typically don't test the internals of the upstream packages, and so making these mocks visible even using feature flags is rather poor practice IMO. Just have tests be within the boundaries of the relevant package.